# How to Convert string in ICandle? C#

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

MVVM , WPF , C#

I do TraidingPlatform and use FancyCandle.

I have ObservableCollection ICandle

Now i need save and open my file.
Saved was done

```
public RelayCommand SaveCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _saveCommand ??
                (_saveCommand = new RelayCommand(() =>
                {
                    var result = new List<string>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < ChartView.Count; i++)
                    {
                        result.Add(ChartView[i].t.ToString());
                        result.Add(ChartView[i].L.ToString());
                        result.Add(ChartView[i].H.ToString());
                        result.Add(ChartView[i].O.ToString());
                        result.Add(ChartView[i].V.ToString());
                        result.Add(ChartView[i].C.ToString());
                    }
                    fileManager.RewriteAllLines(FilePath, result.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList());
                }));
        }
    }
```

But now i dont understand how to Convet from list in ICandle

```
public List<string> GetManyFiles()
    {
        return fileManager.ReadAllLines(FilePath);
    }
    public RelayCommand LoadCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _loadCommand ??
                (_loadCommand = new RelayCommand(() =>
                {
                    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();                      
                    openFileDialog.Filter = "txt files(*.txt)|*.txt|All files(*.*)|*.*";
                    bool? response = openFileDialog.ShowDialog();
                if (response == true)
                {
                    var vals = GetManyFiles();
                    var result = new ObservableCollection<ICandle>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < vals.Count; i++)
                    {
                    }
                    ChartView = result;
                }
                }));
        }
    }
```

Please help me, Thx.

Comment: To save and restore object, see serialization.

Comment: I know it can be done without serialization, But I can't guess how
 ))

Comment: You do serialization, just you don't use standard format like xml or json.

Comment: _"I know it can be done without serialization, But I can't guess how ))"_ - Then you have a whole different problem. How do you "know" it can be done "without serialization"? Why do you "guess" instead of look up documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry

I was not quite right

I done

```
public RelayCommand LoadCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _loadCommand ??
                (_loadCommand = new RelayCommand(() =>
                {
                    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();                      
                    openFileDialog.Filter = "txt files(*.txt)|*.txt|All files(*.*)|*.*";
                    bool? response = openFileDialog.ShowDialog();
                    if (response == true)
                    {
                        ChartView.Clear();
                        //$"{item.O}|{item.H}|{item.L}|{item.C}|{item.t}|{item.V}"
                        var vals = GetManyFiles();
                        foreach(var item in vals)
                        {
                            var args = item.Split('|');
                            ChartView.Add(new Candle(DateTime.Parse(args[4]),
                                                    Convert.ToDouble(args[0]),
                                                    Convert.ToDouble(args[1]),
                                                    Convert.ToDouble(args[2]), 
                                                    Convert.ToDouble(args[3]), 
                                                    Convert.ToInt64(args[5])));
                        }
                    }
                }));
        }
    }
```